# how to update the specific node in xml using Php

Tags: php, xml

It was like inventory system, if i enter the quantity of items i will buy, It must deducted on (products.xml) while saving the ordered products on (orders.xml). It was saving on orders.xml but the stocks is not updating.

The stocks was deducted but only can be seen at the input box, but was not updating at the "products.xml" 
Picture:[The Ordering Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVOrG.png)
Picture: [Xml File is not updating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vq9d.png)

```
<?php

$products =simplexml_load_file("product.xml") or die("ERROR");

foreach ($products->product as $product){
        if($product['id']==$_GET['id']){
            $id = $product['id'];
            $name =$product->name;
            $price = $product->price;
            $stocks = $product->stocks;

            break;
        }

    }


if(isset($_POST['submitSave'])){

    // $name = $_POST['name'];
    // $id = $_POST['id'];
    // $price = $_POST['price'];

    $quan = $_POST['quan'];

    $total = $price * $quan;

    $stocks = $stocks - $quan; // on minusing the stocks :<


    foreach ($products->product as $product){
        if($product['id']==$_POST['id']){
            // $product->name = $_POST['name'];
            // $product->price = $_POST['price'];
            $product->stocks = $_POST['stocks'];
            break;
        }

    }
    file_put_contents('product.xml',$products->asXML());




    $xml = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
    $xml -> preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
    $xml -> formatOutput = true;





    if(file_exists("orders.xml")){
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('orders.xml');
        $order = $xml->addChild('order');
        $order->addChild('id', $id);
        $order->addChild('name', $name);
        $order->addChild('price', $price);
        $order->addChild('quan', $quan);

        $order->addChild('total', $total);


        $xml->saveXML("orders.xml");
        $xml=simplexml_load_file("orders.xml") or die("ERROR");
        $a=1;
        foreach($xml->children() as $order)
        {
        echo"<div class = 'orderlist' ";
        echo"<b>Order No.:". $a++."</b><br>";
        echo"Product Id: ".$order->id."<br>";
        echo"Product Name: ".$order->name."<br>";
        echo"Price: ".$order->price."<br>";
        echo"Quantity Ordered: ".$order->quan."<br>";
        echo"Total Price: ".$order->total."<br>";
        echo"</div><br>";
        }

    }
    else{
        $orders = $xml -> createElement("orders");
        $xml -> appendChild($orders);

        $order = $xml -> createElement("order");
        $orders -> appendChild($order);

        $id = $xml -> createElement("id", $id);
        $order -> appendChild($id);



        $name = $xml -> createElement("name", $name);
        $order -> appendChild($name);

        $price = $xml -> createElement("price", $price);
        $order -> appendChild($price);

        $quan = $xml -> createElement("quan", $quan);
        $order -> appendChild($quan);

        $total = $xml -> createElement("total", $total);
        $order -> appendChild($total);
        //echo "<xmp>" .$xml -> saveXML(). "</xmp>";
        file_put_contents("orders.xml", $xml->saveXML());

        // 



        $xml=simplexml_load_file("orders.xml") or die("ERROR");
        $a=1;
        foreach($xml->children() as $order)
        {
        echo"<div class = 'orderlist' ";

        echo"<b>.Order No.:".$a++."</b><br>";
        echo"Product Id: ".$order->id."<br>";
        echo"Product Name: ".$order->name."<br>";
        echo"Price: ".$order->price."<br>";
        echo"Quantity Ordered: ".$order->quan."<br>";
        echo"Total Price: ".$order->total."<br>";
        echo"</div><br>";
        }
    }
    // file_put_contents('product.xml',$products->asXML());
    // header('location: index.php');
}

?>
<form method="post">
<br><center>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="price" value="<?php echo $price;?>" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Stocks</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="stocks" value="<?php echo $stocks;?>"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="quan" value="" ></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submitSave" value="Buy"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: where abouts in that code are you deducting the stock quantity and saving that xml back to product.xml?

Comment: $stocks = $stocks - $quan; // on minusing the stocks 


    foreach ($products->product as $product){
        if($product['id']==$_POST['id']){
       
            $product->stocks = $_POST['stocks'];
            break;
        }

Comment: is my code right? please help me correct it

Comment: You should change $product->stocks = $_POST['stocks']; to $product->stocks = $stocks;  and if it still isn't saving, perhaps pass by reference in the foreach, eg foreach ($products->product as @$product){ .. :)

Comment: Check that `$_POST['stocks']` contains the correct value your after. Although I would have thought the line should be `$product->stocks = $quan;`